# how to add import for FirebaseList Adapter using FireBaseui:Firebase dependency

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-studio-3.0, firebaseui

I want to retrieve some data from firebase using Firebaselist adapter but
i cannot add dependencies to import `com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;`
it shows  `error` in Android Manifest...something about version
i don't know how to resolve...Please help.
Here is the error message :

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3] C:\Users\Ace ZeQuoX.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-ui-0.4.3.aar\9cbc5b901274191a170b1e36cb26d8d9\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
>       Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
>           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
>           or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

here is my implementation for dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}
```

somewhere in android mainfest file :
-use SDK:

```
android: minSDKVersion = "15"
android: targedSDKVersion = "27"
```

Answer (score 0):

FUI only supports API 16 and onwards so that means you'll have to bump your minSdk to 16.